# Explanation of the differences between GIT and SVN

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I come from an SVN background, and I have a hard time grasping Git's philosophy. In particular, I'm confused by the following.

1. Imagine I have made some changes in my working dir. If I switch to another branch, the changes *remain*, which is very unusual, from an SVN point of view.
   This means that uncommitted changes are *shared* between the branches.
   Moreover, the "stage property" of the files is also *shared* between the branches: if I call `git add *` in one branch, then all the files will be added to next commit in all the branches.
   Looks like my branches differ only by already *committed* files.

   So, if uncommitted data are *shared*, then, no matter which branch I am on now, I will commit *all the staged files*, even if they were added in different branches! As I come from an SVN background, this strikes me as very odd.

   Am I correct, or am I just confused? 
   Why does Git work in this way?
2. Sometimes, Git tells me something like this:

   > Cannot switch to another branch because your changes will be erased. Commit them first.

   In SVN, that's not a problem: branches are *independent*. Why and when does this happen in Git?
3. What's up with the way Git handles folders? If I create a new folder, it is not displayed in Git's status report. Does Git simply not care about folders?

Comment: These should be separate questions.

Comment: Patrick, but all the questions are about GIT concepts.. may be even one convept which I dont get.

Comment: So are **all** the questions under the git tag.  Putting all your questions here makes it hard to search them later and hard for people who know the answer to find them.  Also, if one of your questions was already asked then they could all be marked as a duplicate since there's no way to break them apart.  If I were you I'd edit this to be one of your questions, then create two new questions with the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIT :)
There is a Git way and it is different from SVN way

1. There are three trees: HEAD, Working Copy and Stage (see http://www.infoq.com/presentations/A-Tale-of-Three-Trees), any **uncommited** change you do on working copy and stage **will not** be added to any branch unless you commit them. So uncommited changes **are not** shared between branches, and in fact, uncommited changes doesnt belongs to any branch until you commit them. When you commit your changes, **your changes will go to only ONE branch** (you can commit same changes to different branches using extra commands too, but it comes later)
2. That is because you *cannot switch to another branch because your changes will be erased*, as general rule, you should do checkout (for switching and optionally creating branches), pull, push, merge, rebase only if you have ALL changes commited. Of course you can do this with uncommited changes too, but it is not recommended
3. Git was not designed to handle **empty** folders, so,if you need to have an "empty" folder in your repo, you need to create a hidden file inside the folder (by convention, you can name it ".gitkeep")

Summary:

- On git, there is three basic kind of operations: creating commits (using git add, git commit), handling commits (git merge, git rebase, git checkout), and syncing (git push, git fetch)
- Handling commits (merge, rebase, etc..) is a lot easier on committed changes, **merging uncommited changes is the WRONG WAY in git**
- Always **COMMIT FIRST** and make sure there is no uncommited changes before doing something else (i mean, handling commits like pull, merge, rebase, etc...), if there is uncommited changes remaining on your WC/stage and you don't want to commit them, use **git stash** (and if you want retrieve the changes again using **git stash pop** later)

Comment: dseminara, thanks a lot! but why sometimes I can switch to another branch with uncommitted code, and sometimes I cannot?

Comment: You can switch to different branch with uncommited changes if the other branch has no changes to overwrite. For example, if you change a single file in you working copy and let it uncommited, you can switch to any branch not modifiying the same file. But it's generally not recommended to switch branches with uncommited changes (unless you perfectly know what are you doing)